# c# Unauthorized exception

Tags: c#

Hey guys I got this error I have tried to run program as administrator, no luck still get this error I don't get why it can't clean the shortcuts in the recent documents folder, this is my code:

```
//this will delete the the files in the Recent Documents directory
private void DeleteRecentDocuments(string RecentDocumentsDirectory)
{
    //this is the directory and parameter which we will pass when we call the method
    DirectoryInfo cleanRecentDocuments = new DirectoryInfo(RecentDocumentsDirectory);

    //try this code
    try
    {
        //loop through the directory we use the getFiles method to collect all files which is stored in recentDocumentsFolder variable
        foreach(FileInfo recentDocumentsFolder in cleanRecentDocuments.GetFiles())
        {
            //we delete all files in that directory
            recentDocumentsFolder.Delete();
        }
    }
    //catch any possible error and display a message
    catch(Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error could not clean Recent documents directory, please try again");
    }
}
```

I call this method above but dw bout that too much its just calling the method and parameter is the directory. If you want I can post that to.

Comment: Whats the exception? it works for me when  RecentDocumentsDirectory = @"C:\Users\username\Documents\directory"

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN, `FileInfo.Delete()` will throw `UnauthorizedAccessException` when

[image]

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.delete(v=vs.110).aspx)

In order to delete all the files in a directory could do

```
foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(recentDocumentsFolder))
{
    File.Delete(filePath);
}
```

If you want to delete the entire directory and any files and subfolders within it you could call

```
Directory.Delete(recentDocumentsFolder, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code work for me without any exception, I have select recent document folder using this way and work perfect

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent)
```

here is my test solution using console application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string rd = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent);
            DeleteRecentDocuments(rd);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        //this will delete the the files in the Recent Documents directory
        private static void DeleteRecentDocuments(string RecentDocumentsDirectory)
        {
            //this is the directory and parameter which we will pass when we call the method
            DirectoryInfo cleanRecentDocuments = new DirectoryInfo(RecentDocumentsDirectory);

            //try this code
            try
            {
                //loop through the directory we use the getFiles method to collect all files which is stored in recentDocumentsFolder variable
                foreach (FileInfo recentDocumentsFolder in cleanRecentDocuments.GetFiles())
                {
                    //we delete all files in that directory
                    recentDocumentsFolder.Delete();
                }
            }
            //catch any possible error and display a message
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Update**

some files inside that directory is protected not only for delete but also copy so you can't delete them but most of others can be delete using below code, I have tested

```
 private static void DeleteRecentDocuments(string RecentDocumentsDirectory)
        {
            //this is the directory and parameter which we will pass when we call the method
            DirectoryInfo cleanRecentDocuments = new DirectoryInfo(RecentDocumentsDirectory);

            //try this code
            try
            {
                //loop through the directory we use the getFiles method to collect all files which is stored in recentDocumentsFolder variable
                foreach (FileInfo recentDocumentsFolder in cleanRecentDocuments.GetFiles())
                {
                    //we delete all files in that directory
                    File.Delete(RecentDocumentsDirectory + recentDocumentsFolder);

                }
            }
            //catch any possible error and display a message
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks guys for help I only want to delete the files in the recent documents folder NOT the main folder it self.

Comment: This is what I call the method :       if(ThumbnailCacheBox.Checked == true)
            {
                CleanThumbnailCache(@"C:\Users\"+ System.Environment.UserName + @"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer");
            }

Comment: see my update, some files are not deletable but others can be

Comment: I did thanks you did the file.delete still got same error for some reason maybe its something from my end.